# Issue using While+if statements together in Python

Tags: python, subprocess

Can someone please check below code, as i am using while and If statement together in python and calling one more python code, but it is executing all the code except calling the other python code.

```
import os
import psycopg2
import os.path
import subprocess
import sys

if os.path.isfile("Z:\\xyz\\New.xlsx"):
    while True:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(database="gp_bdl", user="adwed1", password="***", host="bdlgp12", port="6200")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        print ("Opened database successfully")    
        try:
            cur.execute('''select function1();''')
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()

        except psycopg2.OperationalError:
            continue
        break;
        if os.path.isfile("Z:\\xyz\\second.xlsx"):
         print("Next has started")
         subprocess.call([sys.executable,'Next Python.py'])
    else:
         print("Nothing")
else:
   print("No Process")*
```

Comment: Please be more specific - it's unclear what your problem is. Also that first `else` statement is not aligned to an `if` - make sure you are indenting your code correctly

Comment: When I run the mentioned code, it is not executing the second if statement and inturn unable to execute the subprocess

Comment: @UnholySheep I don't know whether it is what OP actually wants, but `while/else` is valid Python syntax.

Comment: that is because you break out of the code, that means that your if statement needs to happend before the break statement

Answer (score 2):

Everything after your `break` statement is dead code. If your `try` raises an error, the `continue` statement is starting a new iteration (different from `pass`, which just keep the flow going from that point).

But if it doesn't raise an exception, you're breaking out of the `while`, so your first `if` in unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import psycopg2
import os.path
import subprocess
import sys

if os.path.isfile("Z:\\xyz\\New.xlsx"):
    while True:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(database="gp_bdl", user="adwed1", password="***", host="bdlgp12", port="6200")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        print ("Opened database successfully")    
        try:
            cur.execute('''select function1();''')
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()

        except psycopg2.OperationalError:
            continue

        if os.path.isfile("Z:\\xyz\\second.xlsx"):
            print("Next has started")
            subprocess.call([sys.executable,'Next Python.py'])
        else:
            print("Nothing")

        break
else:
    print("No Process")*
```

like my comment states it needs to look like this, everything ater the break statement inside the loop won't be executed.

Answer (score 0):

The "break" must be sent to another position (in the exception branche). Else the code part:

```
if os.path.isfile("Z:\\xyz\\second.xlsx"):
    print("Next has started")
    subprocess.call([sys.executable,'Next Python.py'])
```

will never be executed and thus your other file is not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Why does your code don't work? Answer:

- Break breaks the whole loop, remove it!
- Replace "continue" with "pass"
- Remove that tiny * in "print("No Process")*"
- No semicolons in Python!

Fixed code:

```
import os
import psycopg2
import os.path
import subprocess
import sys

if os.path.isfile("Z:\\xyz\\New.xlsx"):
    while True:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(database="gp_bdl", user="adwed1",password="***", host="bdlgp12", port="6200")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        print ("Opened database successfully")    
        try:
            cur.execute('''select function1();''')
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()

        except psycopg2.OperationalError:
            continue
        break
        if os.path.isfile("Z:\\xyz\\second.xlsx"):
            print("Next has started")
            subprocess.call([sys.executable,'Next Python.py'])
    else:
         print("Nothing")
else:
   print("No Process")
```